# Ionic Tabs - angular router changes the url but not the view

Tags: angular, ionic4

I'm trying to use the angular router in an ionic v4 app to load child components onto a view. The url changes but the view does not update.

I've included the ion-router-outlet tag in the parent template, which is supposed to work in the same way that the standard Angular router-outlet tag does, but something seems to be missing.

Parent template:

```
<ion-tabs>
 <ion-tab-bar slot="top">

  <ion-tab-button tab="tab1">
    <ion-label>page 1</ion-label>
  </ion-tab-button>

  <ion-tab-button tab="tab2">
    <ion-label>page 2</ion-label>
  </ion-tab-button>

 </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>

<ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
```

Parent module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        component: ChildComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'tab2',
        component: ChildComponent
      },
      { 
        path: '',   
        redirectTo: '/main/tab1', 
        pathMatch: 'full' 
      }
    ]
  },
  { 
    path: '',   
    redirectTo: '/main/tab1', 
    pathMatch: 'full' 
  }

];
```

I'm not getting any errors in the browser console

Comment: your routes definition went wrong I think.

Answer (score 0):

You try this.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'main',
    component: MainPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        loadChildren: '../tab1/tab1.module#Tab1Module'
      },
      {
        path: 'tab2',
        loadChildren: '../tab2/tab2.module#Tab2Module'
      },
      { 
        path: '',   
        redirectTo: '/main/tab1', 
        pathMatch: 'full' 
      }
    ]
  },
  { 
    path: '',   
    redirectTo: '/main/tab1', 
    pathMatch: 'full' 
  }

];
```